# how can I use my Arduino board's Atmega with ATMEL Studio 7?

Tags: arduino, atmega, firmware, atmelstudio

Basically I just want to use my Arduino Board's Atmega as a normal Atmega. I want to burn the same code that we burn on Atmega32 controller. As we know that we can program Ardunio board with IDE and there is proper syntax style for coding. I want to make just the use of Atmega32 without the Arduino style coding.

Comment: Where did you find an Arduino board that uses the ATmega32?

Comment: If you know how to code the project under Atmel Studio, the problem I understand is to Flash the board. This can be done and is explained here : http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Load-Programs-to-an-Arduino-UNO-From-Atmel-/
If this is not the question, please clarify your question

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure of your question here, but here are some thoughts:
Arduino is programmed over USB using some code that is programmed into the bootloader. If you want to program without Arduino, you will probably overwrite the bootloader which means that you will need an In System Programmer (ISP) for the board. These are separate USB devices that usually use the SPI connections on the chip to upload the program.

Atmel (now Microchip) has their own line of programmers that work with Atmel Studio but you can find some on ebay that pretend to be Atmel programmers for a fraction of the cost.

Another option is a cheap ISP but using AVRDude to upload your code, rather than Atmel Studio. I have never been a fan of Atmel Studio.

Since you are looking to reuse ATmega32 code ( I think that's what you are saying), don't forget to change the target hardware in Atmel Studio so that the port and address defines are changed to the chip you are using (ATMega328P)

Rod

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to overwrite the bootloader unless size is an issue. There is an arduino plugin for atmel studio also Arduino is AVR so just don't use the Arduino.h styling. Create a project using the arduino setup in minimal and simply write straight AVR C into AVR Studio it will compile either on Arduino's end or on Atmels end. You can even keep the arduino's library code and mix the two styles by pulling in Arduino.h into your studio session. If your asking how to dump a .hex file into arduino you need a ISP programmer and that will kill the bootloader when it's flashed.